# Is there a theme function for is_password_protected()?

Tags: theme-development, functions, password

I'm looking at the function and template references and I'm not seeing a way to test for whether a post is protected. Is there a theme function for (something like) `is_password_protected()`?

I'm already using `add_filter( 'the_password_form', 'custom_password_form' );` to override the default form that shows up, but I want to customize some other aspects of the look when a post is password protected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is. It's [post_password_required](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_password_required):

> Whether post requires password and
>   correct password has been provided.

Comment: Doh! How'd I miss that? Thanks for speedy answer!

Comment: You're welcome. It happens pretty often, you need these obvious functions and can't find them... That's when WP Answers comes in :P

Answer (score 2):

Should be done close to this:

```
<?php 
if ( have_posts() ) :

while ( have_posts() ) : 

    if ( post_password_required() ) :
        the_content();
    else :

    endif; // password

endwhile; 
else: 
?>
```